# Expo QR code not showing for a React Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Usually when I run `npm start` / `expo start` the expo CLI starts and I am able to scan the QR code using expo on my phone. However after I start the app a few times, the QR code no longer begins to show up and I can no longer scan it.

[image]
Bottom Lower Corner of the Expo Developer Tools which usually shows a QR code

[image] NPM command prompt running without a QR code

Comment: Try `npm start` using the system terminal. Then see if it works.

Comment: still doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

For me, I also had an error at the top of the console:

`Linking is disabled because the client scheme cannot be resolved`

To resolve, I simply had to run this:

`npx uri-scheme add [your app name]`

It added the uri schemes and the app then showed the QR code.

source: [this issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4140#issuecomment-1018990833)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue when I updated the expo-cli with this command.
`npm install -g expo-cli`

I have followed these steps and worked for me,

1. Stop your expo with command `CTRL+C`
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder in the project
3. Run command `npm install`
4. Run command `npm start`

I hope this would help you.